# MYSQL Insert syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have two codes to put data into database but it is generating error, check out the code below.

```
$email = "example@hotmail.com"; //email

$pass = "helloworld";  //password

$fname = "Example";  //first name

$lname = "Man"; //last name

$birth = "2012-2-1"; //birthday

$gender = "male"; //gender

$site_prefix = "my_"; //table prefix
```

THIS CODE DOESNT WORK AND OUTPUT AN ERROR

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO `{$site_prefix}login` (`email`,`pass`) 
VALUES ('$email','$pass');
INSERT INTO `{$site_prefix}users` (`fname`,`lname`,`birthday`,`gender`)
VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$birth','$gender')";

mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

**ERROR**
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO my_users (`fname`,`lname`,`birthday`,`gender`) VALUES ('Example','Ma' at line 2

THIS CODE WORK NORMALLY

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$site_prefix}login` (`email`,`pass`) VALUES ('$email','$pass');";

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `{$site_prefix}users` (`fname`,`lname`,`birthday`,`gender`) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$birth','$gender')";

mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($sql1,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: do you need quotes on the field name? its needed only for values.. is it http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: @user1335825: I hope those values you're inserting have been properly treated to prevent SQL injection attacks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_query` cannot process multiple statements in one query.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> `mysql_query()` sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified **link_identifier**

Use `mysqli` (with [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)) if you need this functionality.

Comment: Thank alot Quassnoi, but I will still continue with mysql.